# What are the risks of exchanging Bitcoins via Near Field Communication?

Tags: mobile, face-to-face-payment, nfc

What are the risks of exchanging Bitcoins via Near Field Communication? The transaction Parameters might be negotiated via NFC and the actual transaction via Internet.

Answer (score 1):

The risks could be, someone else with a good NFC communicator could intercept your request and make you send some BTC to them, having another persons phone next to yours with the app can do the same, and possibly NFC jammers can really cause a lot of problems with the transfer.

Comment: Can you be more specific?  The paper at http://events.iaik.tugraz.at/RFIDSec06/Program/papers/002%20-%20Security%20in%20NFC.pdf says that a man-in-the-middle attack is impractical.